# In TCL, is there a way to use raw binary values?

Tags: binary, tcl

I'm aware that you can use raw hexadecimal values in TCL, but is there an elegant way to use binary?

I'm trying to do something like

```
if {[expr $var & 11100111b] != 11000001b} { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precede the binary value with `0b`:

```
if {($var & 0b11100111) != 0b11000001} { … }
```